# Android - How to use the android studio project as library

Tags: android, eclipse, jar, android-studio, android-library

**What I Did:** I am developing android application using Eclipse IDE. There is nothing issue on that. But I am struggling to use android studio app with my eclipse app.

**What I want:** I want use a open source android application which is developed using android studio. So I am planning to make that as a library and use it in my eclipse app. But I didn't know, how to convert android studio app as a library.

> After some analysis I got the following possibilities.

1) Convert the eclipse app to android studio app -> But I am not familiar with android studio IDE.

2) android studio app will be converted as .aar format and use it in eclipse-> But there is no tutorial regarding this.

> So can anybody clarify the following things:

1) How can I convert the android studio app into .aar binary format.

2) How to use the .aar in my eclipse application(like jar).

3) Is there anyother way to do my above task.

Answer (score 1):

If you run gradle's compile command then go to the `build` directory for the project you should find the aar has been created, I can't remember the precise directory within build, either `apk` or `libraries` I think.

Taking the short amount of time it takes to learn Android Studio would be a wise move. With the amount of time spent rebooting eclipse when it crashes and fixing or working around bugs from it's conflicting plugins, you'll probably save time overall.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I can get the .aar file from "\application\build\outputs\aar". I will start learn on Android studio side-by-side. But, can you tell me "How to use the .aar in my eclipse application(like jar). is it possible?"

Comment: Oh I thought you had already found that part out. I no longer use Eclipse because of all it's issues so no idea, sorry. Stack Overflow has a lot of results for eclipse library projects though